# How to create multiple objects using a class, where the objects' attributes are inserted by the user?

Tags: python, class

I think I have the basic idea down but I can't really make it work properly. I want to create 5 different objects with their own attributes, 3 each but they have to be inputs. They have to be created using another function which then returns them to show the user and also puts them in a list. This is what I have but and I can't figure out how to make it work:

```
class SmartPhone:
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, cost):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost


manufacturer = input("Εισήγαγε τον κατασευαστή: ")
model = input("Εισήγαγε το μοντέλο: ")
cost = input("Εισήγαγε την λιανική τιμή: ")


def smart_phones(manufacturer, model, cost):
    smartPhones = []
    phone = SmartPhone(manufacturer, model, cost)
    smartPhones.append(phone)
    return "Smartphone: " + str(phone), smartPhones


smart_phones = smart_phones(manufacturer, model, cost)
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(smart_phones)
```

The problem lies in the smart_phones function, basically.

Comment: Note that you are overwriting the function `smart_phones` with the tuple returned by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood your description but I'll try to help.

If you're trying to get 5 different SmartPhone objects, you will need to ask the user for 15 inputs (3 for each different phone). In your code you seem to ask the 3 fields for only once. You're essentialy printing the same object (with the same 3 fields) for 5 times.

Try something like this:

```
class SmartPhone:
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, cost):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost

smartPhones = []

def smart_phones(manufacturer, model, cost):
    phone = SmartPhone(manufacturer, model, cost)
    smartPhones.append(phone)
    return "Smartphone: " + str(phone), smartPhones

for i in range(0, 5):
    smart_phones(input("Εισήγαγε τον κατασευαστή: "),input("Εισήγαγε το μοντέλο: "),input("Εισήγαγε την λιανική τιμή: "))
    
for i in range(1, 6):
    print("Phone " + str(i))
    print("Manufacturer: " + smartPhones[i].manufacturer + " ")
    print("model: " + smartPhones[i].model + " ")
    print("cost: " + smartPhones[i].cost + "\n")
```

Basicly this way you enter each 3 values needed for each phone.
And instead of printing the place of the objects in the memory, you print each of the values within each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending an object of class SmartPhone in your list. That's why print() is returning you the address of the object in the memory. Maybe you want to append a list of manufacturer,model,cost . Something like this:

```
def smart_phones(manufacturer, model, cost):
   smartPhones = []
   phone = SmartPhone(manufacturer, model, cost)
   smartPhones.append([phone.manufacturer,phone.model,phone.cost])
   return "Smartphone: " +  str(smartPhones)
```

Also, you are getting your inputs only once. To create 5 objects do this:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
   manufacturer = input("Creator:")
   model = input("Models:")
   cost = input("Cost:")
   print(smart_phones(manufacturer, model, cost))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `SmartPhone` object, a class method is a good place to encapsulate the necessary I/O.

```
class SmartPhone:
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, cost):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost

    @classmethod
    def from_user(cls):
        manufacturer = input("Εισήγαγε τον κατασευαστή: ")
        model = input("Εισήγαγε το μοντέλο: ")
        cost = input("Εισήγαγε την λιανική τιμή: ")
        return cls(manufacturer, model, cost)


smart_phones = [SmartPhone.from_user() for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To print an object in an understandable way, you need to define either [__repr__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) or [__str__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) methods.

A simple example:

```
class SmartPhone:
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, cost):
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.cost = cost
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A ${self.cost} {self.__class__.__name__}: {self.manufacturer} {self.model}"
```

Define a couple of examples:

```
x=SmartPhone('Apple', '13', 1200)    
y=SmartPhone('Samsung', 'Galaxy', 900)
```

Then make a list of those:

```
li=[x,y]
```

Then you can print at will:

```
>>> print(li)
[A $1200 SmartPhone: Apple 13, A $900 SmartPhone: Samsung Galaxy]

>>> x
A $1200 SmartPhone: Apple 13
```